# Scala Pattern Matching with case statement

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hdp

I am Writing One Dataframe into hive table and  Checking if the process completes successfully (data loading Process in hive) then i want to print  message
"Data Writing Process has been Completed",but if it fails because of some error i.e. (wrong table name,Wrong tablename,syntax error etc.), then it should print
"Data Writing Process has been Failed". I am writing below Code:

```
    import spark.implicits._
    import scala.io.Source
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import scala.util.control.Exception._
    import com.hortonworks.hwc.HiveWarehouseSession
    import com.hortonworks.hwc.HiveWarehouseSession._
    val sparksession1 = SparkSession.builder().appName("Appname")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
    .config("hive.mapred.mode", "nonstrict")
    .config("spark.sql.hive.hiveserver2.jdbc.url", "jdbc:hive2:xxxxxxxx")
    .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
val Hive2 = com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseBuilder.session(sparksession1).build()
    val someDF = Seq((1, 2019),(2, 2019),(3, 2019),(4, 2019),(5, 2019),(6, 2019))
    .toDF("MONTH", "YEAR")
    Hive2.setDatabase("DatabaseName")
    val s= Try {
val result=someDF.write.format("com.hortonworks.spark.sql.hive.llap.HiveWarehouseConnector")
.option("database","DatabaseName").option("table","tablename").mode("append").save()
        }val y = s match {
        case Failure(e) => e match {
    case e: Exception =>
    }
    case Success(s) =>
   }
```

I'm Getting Below Error Message

```
   <console>:4: error: ';' expected but 'match' found.
   } match {
   ^

   scala> case Success(_) =>
   <console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
    case Success(_) =>
    ^
    scala> println("Data Wtriting Process has been Completed")
    Data Wtriting Process has been Completed
    scala> case Failure(_) =>
    <console>:1: error: illegal start of definition
    case Failure(_) =>
    ^
    scala> println("Data Wtriting Process has been Failed")
    Data Wtriting Process has been Failed
    scala>
    | }
    <console>:2: error: eof expected but '}' found.
    }
    ^
```

Can Someone Please Guide me how should i Implement the same.

Note.:I'm Using HDP 3.0 and wrting my application in Spark/Scala.

Comment: don't confuse `try` and `Try`. The latter is an ADT that you can pattern match on. The former requires `finally` or `catch`. You want to do `Try(someDF.write.....) match {...}`

Comment: @sinanspd  yes, it was Try .I have updated the question

Comment: Looks like there is a missing `val` before `result`

Comment: Thanks Mike and sinanspd I have updated the code and  its working Now.only thing is if i am giving wrong tablename or db name in that case also its giving Success.PFB the error message.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException:line 1:93 cannot recognize input near 'dbanme' '.' 'wrongtable' in table name
        
        ... 15 more
s: scala.util.Try[Unit] = Success(())